Weird behaviour of grep with ls and regex
I was playing around learning linux commands when I noticed this weird unusual behaviour of the "grep" command . In the /usr/bin directory , when I run :
me@me-desktop:/usr/bin$ ls -l | grep bashb*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        6988 Mar 31  2024 bashbug

which is expected , but if I do the same outside /usr/bin
me@me-desktop:~/Code/linux$ ls -l /usr/bin | grep bashb*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     1446024 Mar 31  2024 bash
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        6988 Mar 31  2024 bashbug
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        4527 Apr 17  2023 dh_bash-completion
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           4 Aug 20 23:14 rbash -> bash

As you can see it now optionally ignores the last b in bashb.
This happens in many other cases as well . For e.g. if you do apt list | grep lib* , then it lists out the ones with li as well.

See the "DON'T EVER test or filter filenames with grep! " point in the Don't Ever Do These section of FullBashGuide - Greg's Wiki.

Try grep 'bashb*' (in single quotes).

I don't understand the reopen votes here. This is clearly a "using a computer" question, not a programming question. It belongs on [su] or [unix.se], not SO.

bashb* does globbing in ls -l | grep bashb* and matches the file bashbug. Your grep effectively becomes
/usr/bin$ ls -l | grep bashbug

When your current directory does not contain a matching file, bashb* is used as-is, which is also wrong since it will match any file with bash anywhere in it its name, followed by 0 or more b's.
Note that globbing and regex follow different rules.

bashb* in globbing means a file starting with bashb and can then  have any number of characters after it.
bashb* in regex matches bash anywhere in the string and b* means the character b 0 or more times. foobashbbbbbar would match that for example.

greping in the output from ls is generally not a good idea.

When using bashb* "as-is" , why does it treat the last b in this fashion ? The result I want is the 1st bulletpoint in your answer , the result I get is the second . So how can I have grep to interpret bashb* to get the 1st bulletpoint result . This also happens while "grepping" in apt list which I assume works similarly to ls .

@MikeBillings When using bashb* as-is, you get the [tag:regex] bashb* which means, match on bash anywhere on each line. * in regex means match the previous character (or group) 0 or more times. So it means, match on b 0 or more times. You shouldn't really use grep on ls (or apt) output since they don't have  stable and well defined output. You need to know where the filename starts, but look at the timestamps and you'll see the problem. You could do grep ' bashb' (note the space) but if your files have spaces in them it won't work.

your help was valuable but that brings me to a follow-up doubt where I make a text file and paste into it the 2nd output of my question where it uses bashb* as-is , and then run grep 'bashb*' file , how can I make it output just the line where it contains bashbug , not the all the matches with bash ?

@MikeBillings Same thing: grep ' bashb' file - but it's still not a good idea to use grep on output from ls (or apt) even if you've stored that output in a file.

In your first command, the bashb* is expanded by your shell before being passed to grep. This happens because your current directory contains a file which matches the expansion. Thus, the final command which is started is:
cd /usr/bin
ls -l | grep bashbbug

In your second command, you don't have a maching file ~/Code/linux. Thus,. bash does not expand the argument and passes it directly to grep:
cd ~/Code/linux
ls -l | grep bashbb*

To avoid this expansion in any case, you can wrap your argument in single quotes:
cd /usr/bin
ls -l | grep 'bashb*'


I got some insights from the last piece of your answer which cleared upon how it expands bashb* but still could you explain what "grepping" bashb*actually do ? Does it mean just find files starting withbashbor does it have some policy of ignoring the lastb? If the latter is true , why does it work in that manner ? This behavior happens while using grep with apt list` as well which I mentioned in the question. What happens in that case ?

@MikeBillings grep matches its input (in this  case the output of ls -l ) against the given regular expression. Here, the regular expression bashbb* matches lines which contain anywhere the string bashb followed by zero or more b characters. Note that in any case, you can't easily match the output of ls -l with regular expressions. A better solution could be to use find, e.g. find /usr/bin -name "bashb*" -ls. find uses "normal" shell expansion characters to match names with the -name matcher

So when you first said that bashb* "is being expanded by my shell" when searching directly inside the target directory , does it work like pressing Tab  to complete the "bashb" into "bashbug" and then grep bashbug is run?

Yes, the tab expansion feature of your shell works similarly but is not actually involved when running commands; it just uses the same shell expansion logic.
